# How to restrict window.addEventListener to a particular record in LWC

Tags: lwc-dom

I am using an iframe inside lwc component and implemented `window.addEventListener(“message”, handleListener)` to catch the response from iframe. I have added the lwc component to multiple record page. When I am interacting with iframe content the `handleListener` function is getting executed from all the record page but I wanted that to be executed for that particular record. I tried with `this.addEventListener` and `this.template.addEventListener` but that doesn’t work here.

Here is my lwc code

HTML

```
<template>
     <iframe height="650" src=="https://xyz.com" scrolling="true" width="100%" frameborder="false" ></iframe>
</template>
```

js

```
import { api, wire, LightningElement } from 'lwc';             
export default class LM_IframeTest extends LightningElement {
     @api recordId;
    
     constructor() {
        super();
        window.addEventListener('message', this.handleListener);      
     }
    
     handleListener = (event) => {
         console.log('Response from Listener >> ' + event.data);
         console.log('------------recId----------'+this.recordId);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To restrict `window.addEventListener` to a particular page you need control over your iframe code.

If you have that then, append the iframe src value with dynamic record id . For eg: `https://xyz.com?recordId=23423423`.

Then from you iframe you can read this queryParam as:

```
let params = (new URL(window.location)).searchParams;
let recordId = params.get('recordId');

const objData = {
       strDestinationId: 'MessageToParent',
       recordId: recordId
}
parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(objData), '*');
```

And in your Aura or LWC:

```
// get the recordId and store it in a variable `recordId`

window.addEventListener("message", (objEvent) => this.listenForMessage(objEvent));
listenForMessage(objEvent){
    if(objEvent && objEvent.data && typeof objEvent.data === 'string'){
        let parse = JSON.parse(objEvent.data);
        if(parse.strDestinationId === 'MessageToParent' && parse.recordId && parse.recordId === this.recordId){
            // Message coming from proper page
        }
    }
}
```